# How can I set the background with a usleep()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt4.8

I call the function of background two times with two different backgrounds. I setup `usleep(1000)` but does not work. My system is linux and I am run **Qt 4.8**.

main.cpp

```
MainWindow w;
w.setBg('A');
usleep(1000);
w.setBg('B');
```

In the mainwindow.cpp there is `setBg(char c)` with `switch` to select between two backgrounds.

How can I call the first `switch` with `usleep` then switch to the other?

Should I reload my widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks that block the inner loop of the GUI are not correct for this type of tasks, as in your case it is usleep, it is advisable to use a `QTimer` as shown below:

```
/*Qt5*/
MainWindow w;
w.setBg('A');
w.show();

QTimer::singleShot(1 /*in ms*/, [&w](){
    w.setBg('B');
});

/*Qt4*/
/*on MainWindow*/

private slots:
    void mySlot(){
        setBg('B');
    }
/*constructor*/
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(mySlot()));
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I got an error `no matching function to call to QTIMER:: singleShot(int, main(int, char**)::...` and there is a note `candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided` I have added this but does not accept this reference. Should I define `Qtimer` in `mainwindow.h`?

Comment: What version of Qt do you have?

Comment: Qt 4.4 using Creator

Comment: I recommend you put the version of Qt in your question, if you do not indicate, assume that you are talking about the latest version, and from Qt 5.7 supports this new syntax, wait a moment to update my answer for your version.

Comment: Qt4.4 or Qt 4.4 version of Qt Creator? to which you mean, your description is confusing to me. one thing is the Qt library version and another is the Qt Creator IDE version.

Comment: add `CONFIG += c++11` to your .pro and recompile, what is your compiler?

Comment: Are you copying my answer exactly or have you made any modifications?

Comment: Yes, I copying the answer exactly without modifications. I wrote `gcc --version` since my system is Linux Centos 7 and I got `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5...`. **ONE THING**: I installed the latest Qt creator from the resource and Qt in is based on 5.9.1, but when I wrote `qmake -v` I got `the version 3.3.8b`. Which one is correct?

Comment: That's right, it's the Qmake version, do you have a teamviewer to help you?

Comment: You could share your project, I have tried it in Arch Linux, Qt 5.9.1

Comment: Yes, I have, How can I sent to you my teamviewer number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155885/discussion-between-eyllanesc-and-yacacsh).

Comment: Hi, another question related to this one. How can I do your answer but only from `main.cpp`. I mean I don't need to create slot and constructor. If you have an answer please posted.

Comment: @YAcaCsh maybe with something similar to `MainWindow w;
w.setBg('A');
w.show(); QTime time =QTime::currentTime(); while(time.elapsed() < 1000) {qApp->processEvents();} w.setBg('B');` the above is a seucodigo and I have not tested it, but I think you can do it.